# Redirect following onload submission of form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to unobtrusively pass some data into a form and redirect the user to a new page once submitted.

The below code successfully submits the form on page load, but I don't know how to build a script into this to make it redirect to a certain page after submission. At the moment the form just keeps on re-submitting itself and stays on the same page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#wpcf7-f7863-p7865-o1 form").submit();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#wpcf7-f7863-p7865-o1 form").submit(function(e) {

var form = $(this);
var url = form.attr('action');

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           //write code here to redirect to any page
            window.location = "http://google.com";
       }
     });

    // avoid actual submission of form
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. Is this in a separate script tag or to be added to the code in the original post? Please advise and I will test it out? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for helping so far. I'm the type to keep on playing and testing until it is right, but currently all that happens is the form submits on load, and keeps on submitting without the redirect. Do you have an email I can send you my code to? To see if I'm combining yours and mine correctly?